# Replacing multiple objects with another with child

Tags: objects

Im trying to replace several objects with this object/child:

[image: object]

Its just a simple mesh with an empty box as a child..

i tried linking with no avail.. i tried geometry nodes (works for the mesh, but not for the empty object child).
What are my options here?

Edit.. solved using a script, but still curious if theres another solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.